# Activity Monitor (SSMS) timeout error on Sql server instance

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, activity-monitor

**Environment:**

Window server 2012R2: RAM   = 4GB

Sql Server 2008R2: Min server memory = 0MB Max server memory = 2147483647MB

**Background of problem:**

I am managing database of asp.net application and recently application started to crash (when user tried to sign-in to the application; user see timeout exception on the browser).

In order to rectify the issue I set **timeout =1000** in connection string of webconfig file and that resolved the issue.

When application was crashing I tried to turn on the activity monitor on Sql server instance but I coudn't start activity monitor and got following error:

[image]

**My finding so far:**
[image]

I started my quest and troubleshooted and found that there is memory pressure but I need expert advice if there is any link of activity monitor not starting with memory pressure? I know error is from database as Sql server was busy at the time of crash. How I can further troubleshoot the problem?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it contains a lot of images and not enough information that explains the context of the images in relation to where the errors occur. Please add more details to your question and explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Both GUI and your application experience time-out errors. While you cannot change it in GUI you can change it in your application code. Just increase the timeout. And instead of GUI use T-SQL code that executed in SSMS has no timeout at all

Comment: @sepupic I increased the timeout in webconfig file and it solved the problem sorry I forgot to add in question before now I re-written the question please review.

Comment: >>>if there is any link of activity monitor not starting with memory pressure<<< Activity monitor as many others GUI windows has a timeout set that you cannot change. If the query that it sends does not return in 15 seconds(may be less, I didn't ever measure it), it just interrupt query execution. To find out WHAT it's waiting for use sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks while you are waiting for it to execute its query. Of course it can be memory pressure, with 4Gb only...Consider to limit your max memory for SQL Server unless it's already limited by Editiont (in case you use Express Edition)

Comment: I suggest you lower your `Max server memory = 2147483647MB`  so OS has enough memory to do server scoped activity.

Comment: Thanks everyone to for your input and I am glad that you shared your knowledge and increased my knowledge as well.

Comment: FYI, I have a server with 24GB RAM (12GB currently free) and it too comes up with the same error - I think the issue may be compounded by a shortage of physical memory, but the underlying reason for it I have yet to determine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running out of RAM on the server. One of the comments refers to lowering your Max Server Memory setting. For an instance with only 4GB RAM (which is not really enough to run SQL Server), your Max Server Memory should be set to 2048MB at most, possibly even lower.

Comment: I love that he has RESOURCE_MEMPHYSICAL_LOW highlighted.

Comment: I requested to add 2GB of more memory into Server.
I am limiting Max memory to 2048MB as @Rabdolph advised how about Min memory? should I also set Min memory = 1024MB. So that Sql server don't release 1024MB to OS and keep performing internal tasks as usual.

Comment: Minimum should be left as is. I’ve never changed that setting on a production SQL Server instance in my entire working career.

Comment: Thanks @Randolph your knowledge rocks. I am sharing a good article for others who come to this question and may find [this](https://blobeater.blog/2017/03/01/sql-server-target-vs-total-memory/) article helpful.

Comment: You can also read my own page about memory on https://bornsql.ca/memory

Comment: @RandolphWest I am bit confuse here help me if you can as my Sql server appetite for memory has grown so that means they are some new process/tasks are running which were not running before  if I set Max memory = 2048. Will this limit/ halt tasks/process in Sql server? Or in easy terms if 2048MB is not enough for Sql server will it stop tasks/processes? BTW I ran your script against my production DB and values are as followed:PR:4095, CV & RV:2147483647, RV:1024

Comment: It’ll just make the queries run slightly slower and make more use of TempDB.

Comment: if queries will run slower then does that indicates User will have slower response time from asp.net application? or queries only in SSMS will be slower?

Comment: Try it and see. The fact is 4GB isn’t enough for what you’re trying to do.